# How to obtain the phone number when reading facebook contacts

Tags: api, facebook

I thought it was impossible to read phone numbers of contacts using facebook APIs, but **"Facebook for HTC Sense"** android application is syncing all that information to my local agenda.

Somebody knows how are they implementing this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Is it for people you already have in your contacts?  It's possible they are just cross-referencing other pieces of information (like email) against your local contact info.

Because phone number isn't a field [in the graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) nor is it one in the [corresponding FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user).

Comment: No, they are not in my contacts.  I know the official Facebook API and that's why I was surprised by this feature.  Perhaps they have access to a priviliged API?

Answer (score 0):

The fql fields are "cell" and "other_phone" but they are not available unless your app is whitelisted like obviously their iphone/android apps are.  You can request those fields but they will return back null values, confirming those are the fields (requesting fields that don't exist throws errors).